# XMLHttpRequest File(Image) Upload with Vanillia Javascript to Python

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, xmlhttprequest, cgi

I have a form in a HTML document with and input field for images. If a picture has been selected, it will be previewed and uploaded. Now i am kind of stupid for uploading the file and run into errors. The Webserver respond 500 Internal Server Error and in the logfile i have following error:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage(), referer: referer: mysite.wft/test
self.file.write(data), referer: mysite.wft/test
TypeError: must be str, not bytes, referer: mysite.wft/test
Premature end of script headers: ajcgi.py, referer: mysite.wft/test
```

Maybe someone can help me to see where my mistake is?
The HTML Form looks like this:

```
<form>
      <input id="cam" name="cam" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="myfunc()">
</form>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

The Javascript looks like this:

```
  function myfunc() {

      var file = document.getElementById('cam').files[0];
      var reader  = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e)  {
          var image = document.createElement("img");          
          image.src = e.target.result;
          document.getElementById('preview').appendChild(image);

          var fxhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          fxhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (fxhr.readyState === 4 && fxhr.status === 200) {

                  console.log(fxhr.responseText); 
              } else if(fxhr.readyState == 4){

            console.log(fxhr.responseText); 
              }
          };         

          fxhr.open("post", "mysite.wft/ajcgi.py", true);

          fxhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
          fxhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
          fxhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.size);
          fxhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Type", file.type);

          fxhr.send(e.target.result);                 
       }

       reader.readAsDataURL(file);

   }
```

The Python 3.6 Formhandler should in the first step just return the fiedlstorage object. But just fails. The code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-    
import cgi
import os    
import sys     
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
print('Content-Type: text/html')
print('')
print(form)
```

The idea is to store the file later in a database as BLOB but this is future at this time. At the moment i would be happy to UNDERSTAND where is my mistake and how i can write this correctly.

Thanks

By the way I just want to use plain JavaScript NO Jquery

Comment: Try opening the file handler as a binary file. `fd = open('filename', 'wb')`

Comment: @Dan does not make any difference. What do you expect with the file opening? Would i have the chance there to see the fieldStorage Object? Or I am totally misunderstand here?

Comment: After you call write you get this error: `TypeError: must be str, not bytes` So change the file handle to expect bytes.

Comment: thanks that worked